# Make txt file for data per month back up

Tags: php

I have a query data that i need to back up per month, so I make a txt file per month ex: jan.txt, feb.txt..

My question is how to join that txt file into single txt file?? I want that file content look like this array `jan;data1;feb:data1;mar;data1`

My problem is if for ex. i only have oct.txt this month and i write the content to this file called 2013.txt for example (i know how to do this), but the next month i will have file nov.txt and simply write the content into 2013.txt then the previous data of oct.txt will be replaced by nov.txt data... So how to make this data not replaced one another??

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, it is not possible to answer. What exactly is your problem? Why can't you simply open a file and write the content you want into it? Also show what you tried so far and why this did not work for you please.

Comment: My problem is if for ex. i only have oct.txt this month and i write the content to this file called 2013.txt for example (i know how to do this), but the next month i will have file nov.txt and simply write the content into 2013.txt then the previous data of oct.txt will be replaced by nov.txt data...
So how to make this data not replaced one another??

Comment: Well, just open and append the text. No need to replace the content. Read the manual of the file functions!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$file_name = date("M").'.txt';
$file = fopen($file_name, "a+");
fwrite($file, "Monthly backup");
?>
```

This will automatically create a monthly text file

Comment: so this "a+" mode will always put the new data after the previous data??OK i will try it and tell you the result soon..thanks

Comment: thank you @Nes..you show me the way to start it..this is the code I make for my function..
`for($j=1;$j<13;$j++){
 $file_bln_ke = $dir."/".$j.".txt";
 $read_bln_ke{$j} = fopen($file_bln_ke,"r");
 $get_bln_ke{$j} = fgets($read_bln_ke{$j});
 fclose($read_bln_ke{$j});
 
 //i repeat this until month 12nd
 $getAllData = $get_bln_ke{1}.";".$get_bln_ke{2}.";";
 
 $allData_path = $dir."/data_tahun_".$thn.".txt";
 $inputAllData = fopen($allData_path,"w");
 fwrite($inputAllData, $getAllData);
 fclose($inputAllData);
}`